# How to use OData in Node JS and which package is used to create OData server

Tags: node.js, odata

I am new to OData and I need to know how to use it with Node JS, I cant find any examples related to implementation of OData with Node JS. And which package is used to implement the OData features in Node JS.

I see some packages are deprecated `npm i @odata/server` though

can anyone provide basic implementation of OData with Node JS ? Example request for registering user and response structure ?

Any tips or guidance are much appreciated

I need to create a user registration system, specifically using OData.